# Point.py printing but stops printing

Tags: python

Okay so I'm almost done with this thing. So I got stuck on a double loop and it doesn't print after the print(winnings) so something isn't right but I'm not sure what's wrong but here's the code. And it didn't store the note or alerts or points for just 1 player. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

```
    winnings = [] 
    for n in range(len(ratios)):
      winnings.append(pot*ratios[n])
    print(winnings) #STOPS HERE
    for winning in winnings[1:]:
      # loop over all but the first element in winnings
      winning = int(winning)
      for i, player in enumerate(players[1:]):
        # loop over all but the first player, adding indices
        notes.store("~lottery~", player, "The system has placed you %s in the lottery. The lottery awarded you %s P$" % (Point.ordinal(i), winning), time.time())
        alerts.append(player)
        point = Point.dPoint[player] + winning
        Point.dPoint[player] = point
    return True
  elif len(players) == 0:
```

Comment: Is `winnings` a list of length one, perhaps?

Comment: Well when I was testing it there was only 1 thing in the winnings list so yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `winnings` is a list of length 1, then the `for o in range(1, len(winnings)):` loop will not execute the loop body as the range is empty:

```
>>> list(range(1, 1))
[]
```

If you did not mean to skip the first element, don't start the range at `1`, loop from `0` instead:

```
>>> range(0, 1)
[0]
```

Python indices are 0-based.

Note that in Python, you generally loop over lists *directly*, instead of generating indices, then index. Even if you still need the loop index *as well*, you'd use the `enumerate()` function to add indices for you to the loop:

```
winnings = [pot * ratio for ratio in ratios]
for winning in winnings[1:]:
    # loop over all but the first element in winnings
    winning = int(winning)
    for i, player in enumerate(players[1:]):
        # loop over all but the first player, adding indices
        notes.store("~lottery~", player, 
            "The system has placed you {} in the lottery. The lottery awarded "
            "you {} P$".format(Point.ordinal(i), winning), time.time())
        alerts.append(player)
        Point.dPoint[player] += winning
```

If you needed to pair up *all* winnings with *all* players, use `zip()`:

```
winnings = [pot * ratio for ratio in ratios]
for i, (winning, player) in enumerate(zip(winnings, players)):
    winning = int(winning)
    notes.store("~lottery~", player, 
        "The system has placed you {} in the lottery. The lottery awarded "
        "you {} P$".format(Point.ordinal(i), winning), time.time())
    alerts.append(player)
    Point.dPoint[player] += winning
```

Comment: Ah so how would I make it work if it's a list of one or more?

Comment: @user3103923: Well, what do you *expect to happen* in that case? Why are you looping over indices 1 through to last instead of 0 through to last?

Comment: Well for the players part of the loop I needed to start at 1 and not 0.

Comment: Sure, but you start the `winnings` loop at 1. If that wasn't the plan, then don't do that. :-)

Comment: Well I wanted to start at 1 with the winnings and players.

Comment: So that my Point.ordinal would work because of the placing in the lottery starts at 1st place.

Comment: Sure, but that's only for your `players` loop. Not your `winnings`.

Comment: Sorry, what will get everything from both lists? Looping over all values in `winnings` won't influence what is looped over for the `players` loop.

Comment: Ah okay. So I tried that but it didn't store the note or append my name in alerts or give me my winnings. I also updated the code :3

Comment: @user3103923: You are generating `winnings` just in the lines before the loop (which I replaced with a list comprehension); it is still not clear to me why you need to skip the first value.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that xD. And it's still not doing the notes.store, the alerts, and points. If it helps I have the link to the whole module http://bpaste.net/show/165936

Comment: Well, how many players are there? If there is only one player, then the `players` loop will, again, not execute. These are basic constructs.

Comment: Yeah. And if a user uses the command buy lottery it appends them to player. So the list has a random amount of players. So it can be 1, 2, 3 and so on

Comment: @user3103923: So why are you still confused as to when a loop should execute? If there is only one player and you tell Python to loop over all players *except the first player*, and there is only one player, why is it not clear that the loop will do nothing at all?

Comment: So what would happen if I remove [1:]? Would that fix it?

Comment: Yes, then you loop over **all** players.

Comment: Just on players or also winnings?

Comment: Do you have a clear model of what you are trying to do at all here? I am not really planning to go and work out your application for you; that is well beyond the scope of your question here. If your algorithm requires you to loop over all values in both the `winnings` and `players` sequences, then do so. If your algorithm requires you to skip the first value in either one of them, then do so.

Comment: There is no skipping and heres the most updated one at this time http://bpaste.net/show/165939

Comment: Did you need to pair up winnings with players perhaps? You now apply each winning to all players.

Comment: To make more sense of what the code is suppose to do. First it gets ratios and then multiply the pot with the ratios to get the winnings. After that it stores a note saying the place you are in the list like 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc and how much you win from the winnings. Then it appends your name to the alerts.txt and then adds the winnings to your points total. And then returns True

Comment: Yeah they need to pair up xD

Comment: Like the person in 1st place aka the players[0] would get the ratios[0]. and then the 2nd place person aka players[1] would get the ratios[1] and so forth